# The best way to add stylesheets to WordPress

Tags: theme-development, wp-enqueue-style

I am in the process of converting a mobile responsive page, currently built in Bootstrap into WordPress.

Using `wp_register_style()` and `wp_enqueue_style()` will add the stylesheets to all pages, including the wp-admin. I know I could get around that by using an `if ( ! is_admin() )` conditional statement.

Is it better to use the conditional statement, or to just to use:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/bootstrap.css" media="screen" />
```

in the theme's header.php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To load scrpits only in front-end pages use:

```
 add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_front_end_scripts' );
 function my_front_end_scripts(){
     wp_enqueue_script('script_handle');
     wp_enqueue_style('style_handle');
 }
```

To load scripts only in login use:

```
 add_action( 'login_enqueue_scripts', 'my_login_scripts');
 function my_login_scripts(){
     wp_enqueue_script('script_handle');
     wp_enqueue_style('style_handle');
 }
```

To load scripts only in admin use:

```
 add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts','my_admin_scripts');
 function my_admin_scripts(){
     wp_enqueue_script('script_handle');
     wp_enqueue_style('style_handle');
 }
```

Comment: Will the `wp_enque_scripts` add these styles to '/wp-login.php'?

Comment: I was confused with wp_enqueue_script and wp_enqueue_scripts (note the last 's'). Read again my answer, I've edited it.

Comment: Crystal clear, gave you the answer for this one since this is much more elaborate. Thanks!

Comment: `my_front-end_scripts` will fail as functions can't use hyphens

Answer (score 5):

You should always use `wp_enqueue_style()` and `wp_enqueue_script()` where possible, unless it it a special case such as the HTML5 Shiv script which requires IE conditional comments.

If you use the proper hooks to enqueue your style, it should only be loaded on the front-end. The correct hook to use in your instance would be `wp_enqueue_scripts`, which works for both scripts and styles **on the front-end only**.

```
function theme_name_styles() {

    /* Enqueue the stylesheet. See the Codex for more options */
    wp_enqueue_style( 'theme-name-bootstrap', get_template_directory_uri() . '/boostrap.css' );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_name_styles' );
```

If you want to load styles or scripts on the login page or the admin area, use `login_enqueue_scripts` or `admin_enqueue_scripts`, respectively.

I recommend that you read the Codex pages for the functions [`wp_enqueue_style()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_style) and [`wp_enqueue_script()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script), as well as the pages for the action hooks [`wp_enqueue_scripts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_enqueue_scripts), [`login_enqueue_scripts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/login_enqueue_scripts), and [`admin_enqueue_scripts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_enqueue_scripts).

Comment: Thanks, this makes so much more sense than the last answer. I have since discovered a theme that uses bootstrap dependencies, which does this the same way. Thanks for your help! This make things much clearer to me.

Answer (score 0):

Just a note on `login_enqueue_scripts`: the scripts and styles enqueued on this hook will render in the source of your page just before `</body>` (as of WordPress 3.6.1). See a disscution about style links in body here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4957446/load-external-css-file-in-body-tag

If you need to put your scripts and styles for the login page on the `<head>` you'd be better off using `login_head` hook and echo-ing your links:

```
add_action( 'login_head', 'wp240913_login_head' );
function wp240913_login_head() {
    echo '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="' . get_bloginfo('stylesheet_directory') . '/some.css" />';
    echo '<script type="text/javascript" src="' . get_bloginfo('stylesheet_directory') . '/some.js"></script>';
}
```