# Add Custom Script in Other Plugin's Options page

Tags: admin, wp-admin, options

I am trying to put a custom inline JavaScript is an options page created by a plugin.
The page URL is like this `wp-admin/admin.php?page=psbg`.

This is the code I am using to output my script at the head.

```
function add_scripts() {
    $current_screen = get_current_screen();

    if ( $current_screen = 'admin.php?page=psbg' ) {
        // My codes here
    }
}
add_action( 'admin_head', 'add_scripts' );
```

That's not working. But if I change the compare value of `$current_screen` to

```
if ( $current_screen = 'admin.php' ) {
    // My codes here
}
```

it works, but adds the code to every page with the parent page of `admin.php`.

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

There are several ways to add scripts only to certain admin pages. The best option, from my point of view, is to hook into `admin_enqueue_scripts` and use the `$hook` parameter:

```
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'cyb_admin_scripts');
function cyb_admin_scripts( $hook ) {

    //You may need adjustment here to match for page
    //If the URL of your page is admin.php?page=psbg, the hook
    // to check would be toplevel_page_psbg
    if( $hook == 'toplevel_page_my-page-slug' ) {

        wp_register_script('my-script', plugins_url() . '/my-plugin/js/script.js', array('jquery'));
        wp_register_style('my-style', plugins_url() . '/my-plugin/css/style.css');
        wp_enqueue_style('my-style');
        wp_enqueue_script( 'my-script');

    }

}
```

Other common way I see often is using the [load-page action](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/load-%28page%29) to enqueue the files. For example:

```
//Adding the menu in admin area
add_action('admin_menu', 'cyb_add_menu');
function cyb_add_menu(){

    $hook_suffix = add_menu_page(__('Page title'), __('Menu title'), 'manage_options', 'my-page-slug', 'display_callback_fn');
    // Call to cyb_settings_page_load() when our page is loaded
    add_action( 'load-'. $hook_suffix, 'cyb_settings_page_load' );  

}

function cyb_settings_page_load() {
    //Enqueue styles and scripts
    wp_enqueue_script('my-script', plugins_url() . '/my-plugin/js/script.js', array('jquery'));
    wp_enqueue_style('my-style', plugins_url() . '/my-plugin/css/style.css');
}

function display_callback_fn() {
    //Build your page hiere
}
```

Comment: I really appreciate your help, I really do, but none of them worked in my case.

Comment: Really? I've tested the code before posting and it works perfectly. Have you verify the variables values? You have to modify some of them to match your page. See comments in the code I posted in the answer.

Comment: I did mate, the second option isn't for me as I am trying to put code at a page created by another plugin.. And, at the first option, I changed the `if( $hook == 'toplevel_page_my-page-slug' ) {` to `if( $hook == 'toplevel_page_psbg' ) {`. But not sure why that didn't work.

Comment: I've created the page `wp-admin/admin.php?page=psbg` and tested the code again and it works checking `if( $hook == 'toplevel_page_psbg' ) `. Can you make a `var_dump($hook)` inside `cyb_admin_scripts()` function to see the value you get in `wp-admin/admin.php?page=psbg`?

Comment: `string(19) null`  http://awesomescreenshot.com/0bc3d98s6c

Comment: NULL? Thats quite wire man, the `$hook` parameter has always some value in a valid wp-admin page. Can you try `var_dump(get_current_screen());` inside `cyb_admin_scripts()`?

Answer (score -1):

After a simple `print_r` of the `get_current_screen();` reveled what I need.

This is what worked..

```
function add_scripts() {
    $current = get_current_screen();

    if ( $screen->parent_base == 'psbg' ) {
        // My codes here
    }
}
add_action( 'admin_head', 'add_scripts' );
```

Comment: I'm sorry to downvote but scripts in admin area should be registered/added using `admin_enqueue_scripts` action hook.

Comment: @cybmeta No, its not, specially when I have only couple of lines of JavaScript. Can you show me any documentation about that? And, no problem for the downvote.

Comment: The codex is a good documentation to start: http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_enqueue_scripts There are some questions and answers in this site about this issue. For example http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/112352/the-best-way-to-add-stylesheets-to-wordpress It doesn't matter how many lines of code you have, the action hook `admin_enqueue_scripts` is designed to enqueue scripts and styles in admin area and it the one that should be used for that purpose.